# Secure web api, my public / private key workflow. How to incorporate symmetric key?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Looks like the solutions out there for securing ASP.NET Web API is pretty scattered, so I decided to roll my own public/private key encryption scheme. Please take a look at my workflow and help me answer a question I'm stuck on at the end.  (Again, it's specific to .NET 4.0 Web API framework)

1. User register at my Web MVC 4.0 website.
2. Once registered, my website does 4 things

   a) Generate a RSA **server** public key for this user

   b). Generate a RSA **server** private key for this user

   c). Generate a RSA **client** public key for this user

   d). Generate a RSA **client** private key for this user
3. I save all 4 keys to this user account in database and give the user the server public key, called the "APIKey" as well as the client private key, called "SecretKey". This is for future handshake purpose.  User will never know about the server private key nor the client public key.
4. Once user confirms they have the keys, I delete the "client private key" from my database for security purpose.
5. User starts to request my WebAPI authentication service by submitting the server public key (or APIKey)+":"+encrypted message of (username,password) using the RSA server public key (APIKey)
6. Server receives the APIKey+":"+encrypted message, find the private key, decrypt the message, get username,password, and use Membership provider to make sure they are correct.
7. If not correct, then create a denied response. Otherwise, it finds the Client Public Key on record for the user, create a unique time sensitive session token (expires in 5 minutes), record it in database + time created, and use the client public key to encrypt the token and send it back to the client.
8. Client receives the response, use it's "Client private key" or "Secret Key" to decrypt the response, get the token.
9. User makes other requests to the service by using Server Public Key to encrypt the following

   a) session token
   b) timestamp  (so I can make sure replay attack doesn't happen)
   c) data

and send to the server its APIKEy+":"+encrypted message

What i'm stuck on is step 9 and beyond.

Is that necessary at step 9 to still use public / private key to communicate? The reason I'm asking is because browsers communicate with servers through SSL, at the end,  once handshake happens, they use an agreed cipher suite symmetric algorithm to pass message back and forth, supposedly it's faster? But if we do that, will it be secure from this point on wards?

In that case, where in my workflow can I exchange this agreement between my Web API and Client to use the same symmetric algorithm to encrypt/decrypt information back and forth?

Thanks!!

Edit: If you see a flaw in this workflow, please do let me know! Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to make a secure authentication without need for domains/user auth so you want server client cert exchange right?  ATK is right if you just want encrypted traffic (which you should use anyway for the exchange), but for actually using it as auth, this article is really useful: http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/

Answer (score -1):

**Please don't roll your own scheme**.  Crypto is very hard to get right, even by the experts.   A very subtle error can completely remove all security provided by the scheme.  Just look at the  attacks on SSL/TLS over the past few years for examples.

You mention a "web api" but it's unclear exactly what protocol you are using.  If you are using SOAP, use "Web Security" (WS), which is well defined for SOAP.  If you are communicating over HTTP (ex REST), use HTTPS.  If you are communicating over a connected channel, use TLS or SSH.

EDIT: Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833994(v=vs.108).aspx,

> ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP
>   services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and
>   mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is an ideal platform for building
>   RESTful applications on the .NET Framework

This means you probably want to use HTTPS.